# How to add a bash array into the fields of a JSON array using jq?

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

I currently have the following JSON output from `echo $items | jq`:

```
{
  "Family_Name": "Type 1",
  "Quantity_On_Hand": "335"
}
{
  "Family_Name": "Type 2",
  "Quantity_On_Hand": "215"
}
{
  "Family_Name": "Type 9",
  "Quantity_On_Hand": "159"
}
{
  "Family_Name": "Type 4",
  "Quantity_On_Hand": "500"
}
```

I also have a bash array `colors` of the same size looking like

```
"Blue" "Red" "Green" "Blue"
```

How can I use `jq` so that I get something like

```
{
  "Family_Name": "Type 1",
  "Quantity_On_Hand": "335",
  "Colors": "Blue"
}
{
  "Family_Name": "Type 2",
  "Quantity_On_Hand": "215",
  "Colors": "Red"
}
{
  "Family_Name": "Type 9",
  "Quantity_On_Hand": "159",
  "Colors": "Green"
}
{
  "Family_Name": "Type 4",
  "Quantity_On_Hand": "500",
  "Colors": "Blue"
}
```

I tried using something like `jq --arg` or `jq -n '.{} |= [$colors]'` but cannot get it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jq 1.5 or later, with your input (i.e., a stream of JSON objects) and

```
colors=("Blue" "Red" "Green" "Blue")
```

the following produces an array of the desired JSON objects:

```
jq -s '
  ($ARGS.positional | map({Colors: .})) as $colors
  | [., $colors] | transpose | map(add)
' --args "${colors[@]}"
```

If you want the result to be a stream of the JSON objects, you could tack on `[]` or
change `transpose | map(add)` to `transpose[] | add`

### Caveats

(1) The above solution will work even if some colors have spaces in their names, but in general it may be necessary to pass in the contents of the array using some other mechanism.

(2) If your jq does not support positional parameters (--args), now may be a good time to upgrade; if that is not an option, you could devise a workaround, e.g. using the --argfile option if your jq supports that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that has been tested with versions of jq from 1.4 onwards:

```
jq -R -s --argfile json <(echo "$items") '
  (split("\n") | map(select(length>0))) as $colors
  | [ range(0; $colors|length) | $json[.] + {Colors: $colors[.]} ]
' <( printf "%s\n" "${colors[@]}" )
```

The subtlety here is that `-argfile` will combine the stream of JSON objects into a single array.