# How to insert data into JSON line by line?

Tags: json, bash, sed, jq

I have a json file `data.json` and a text file `values.txt` with line by line aligned data

data.json

```
{"_id": 1, "content": "apple"}
{"_id": 2, "content": "banana"}
```

values.txt

```
red
yellow
```

My desired output looks something like follows, where I want to insert a new field `color` into `data.json` into each line with values from `values.txt`.

output.json

```
{"_id": 1, "content": "apple", "color": "red"}
{"_id": 2, "content": "banana", "color": "yellow"}
```

What would be the fastest and easiest shell tool to do this?

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64623254/how-to-add-a-bash-array-into-the-fields-of-a-json-array-using-jq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interlace data with values and stream to JQ, there you can add each pair together.

```
$ paste -d '\n' data.json values.txt | jq -Rc 'fromjson + {color: input}'
{"_id":1,"content":"apple","color":"red"}
{"_id":2,"content":"banana","color":"yellow"}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple jq-only solution:

```
< values.txt jq -nR --slurpfile json data.json '
  [ $json, [{color: inputs}] ] | transpose | map(add)[]
'
```

Drop the trailing `[]` if you want the result as an array.

Comment: A small detail: This version needs a shell as a helper to read the file and pass its content to jq. jq can read the file itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ paste data.json values.txt | sed 's/}.*[[:space:]]\(.*\)/, "color": "\1"}/'
{"_id": 1, "content": "apple", "color": "red"}
{"_id": 2, "content": "banana", "color": "yellow"}
```

or assuming the string being appended doesn't contain `&`:

```
$ paste data.json values.txt | awk '{sub(/}.*/,", \"color\": \"" $NF "\"}")}1'
{"_id": 1, "content": "apple", "color": "red"}
{"_id": 2, "content": "banana", "color": "yellow"}
```

or if it can contain `&` then:

```
$ paste data.json values.txt | awk '{col=$NF; sub(/}.*/,""); print $0 ", \"color\": \"" col "\"}"}'
{"_id": 1, "content": "apple", "color": "red"}
{"_id": 2, "content": "banana", "color": "yellow"}
```

The above also assume that none of your data contains `}`.

Answer (score 1):

An efficient jq-only solution:

```
< data.json jq -n --rawfile values values.txt '
  ($values | split("\n")) as $values
  | foreach inputs as $in (-1; .+1; $in + {color: $values[.] })
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU parallel):

```
parallel -q echo '{=1s/}//=}, "color": "{2}"}' :::: jsonFile ::::+ valueFile
```

Emulate pasting and build the output from the manipulated arguments.

Or use a couple of sed invocations:

```
sed 'R valueFile' jsonFile | sed -E 'N;s/}\n(.*)/, "color": "\1"}/'
```